# Skipping blanks when appending columns in a sheet (csv) to lists in python

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop, wxpython

So this is my code, and I am trying to append info from a csv file into lists. I'm trying to avoid appending the blanks. The first for loop I've put in seems to do the trick but only for lines[0]. I need to do the same for lines [1],lines [2],lines [3] but it never works for the second loop. I tried an nested for loops which didn't work either. Is there a way I can simplify this and ensure blanks are omitted for each item in lines. (lines [0]) is pretty much like the first column of the sheet etc.  Thank you.

````
import wx


with open('info.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    dropdown_initials = []
    dropdown_printerID = []

    for lines in csv_reader:
        if lines[0] in (None,''):
            continue
        dropdown_initials.append(lines[0])
    print (dropdown_initials)

    for lines in csv_reader:
        if lines[1] in (None,''):
            continue
        dropdown_printerID.append(lines[1])
    print (dropdown_printerID)```


sample for csv: 

User,Object id 1,Info 1 
User2,object id 2,Info 2
User3,object id 3,Info 3
,object id 4,Info 4
,object id 5,Info 5
,,Info 6
,,Info 7
,,Info 8
,,Info 9
,,Info 10
````

Comment: Could you add a sample content for your info.csv, please?

Comment: Hey ive added an example, does that help? Sorry, I'm new at posting and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv


with open(r"Yourfile.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    dropdown_initials = []
    dropdown_printerID = []

    for lines in csv_reader:
        if lines[0].strip():
            dropdown_initials.append(lines[0].strip())
        if lines[1].strip():
            dropdown_printerID.append(lines[1].strip())
    print (dropdown_initials)
    print (dropdown_printerID)
```

I have also added the strip() to make sure you are not appending the spaces as values.

Comment: I think, this is the right answer, though I would add a note regarding @user12151872 approach: _but it never works for the second loop._ - csv_reader object isn't expected to be iterated more than once, because `csv.reader` => *The returned object is an iterator*. Refer to http://zetcode.com/lang/python/itergener/ for more details.

Comment: @slackmart absolutely, that is the very reason. Sorry, I missed to explain the reason why it was not working. Thanks for bringing it up. :-)